# Speeding up setFormula Google Apps Script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a script which does exactly what I intend it to do. It sets needed formats and especially it sets formulas to intended cells. However, the problem is that it's extremely slow. How can I speed it up? I've tried looking into using "getLastRow" or similar so I don't have to batch it to e.g. G4:G1000 but I can't wrap my head around it.

Here is the script:

```
function NumberFormat() {  

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

    var range1 = sheet.getRange("G4:G1000");
  range1.setNumberFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

    var range2 = sheet.getRange("H4:H1000");
  range2.setNumberFormat("hh:mm");

  var range3 = sheet.getRange("I4:I1000");
  range3.setFormula('=IF(G4="","",WEEKNUM(G4)&"/"&YEAR(G4))');

  var range4 = sheet.getRange("J4:J1000");
  range4.setFormula('=IF(G4="","",MONTH(G4)&"-"&YEAR(G4))');

  var range5 = sheet.getRange("U4:U1000");
  range5.setFormula('=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--($K$2:$T$2=U$2)*($K4:$T4<>"N/A"),$K$3:$T$3,$K4:$T4)/SUMIFS($K$3:$T$3,$K$2:$T$2,U$2,$K4:$T4,"<>N/A"),"")');
   range5.setNumberFormat("0.0%");

    var range6 = sheet.getRange("V4:V1000");
  range6.setFormula('=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--($K$2:$T$2=V$2)*($K4:$T4<>"N/A"),$K$3:$T$3,$K4:$T4)/SUMIFS($K$3:$T$3,$K$2:$T$2,V$2,$K4:$T4,"<>N/A"),"")');
     range6.setNumberFormat("0.0%");

  var range7 = sheet.getRange("W4:W1000");
  range7.setFormula('=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--($K$2:$T$2=W$2)*($K4:$T4<>"N/A"),$K$3:$T$3,$K4:$T4)/SUMIFS($K$3:$T$3,$K$2:$T$2,W$2,$K4:$T4,"<>N/A"),"")');
     range7.setNumberFormat("0.0%");  

   var range8 = sheet.getRange("X4:X1000");
  range8.setFormula('=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--($K$2:$T$2=X$2)*($K4:$T4<>"N/A"),$K$3:$T$3,$K4:$T4)/SUMIFS($K$3:$T$3,$K$2:$T$2,X$2,$K4:$T4,"<>N/A"),"")');
     range8.setNumberFormat("0.0%");

   var range9 = sheet.getRange("Y4:Y1000");
  range9.setFormula('=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--($K$2:$T$2=Y$2)*($K4:$T4<>"N/A"),$K$3:$T$3,$K4:$T4)/SUMIFS($K$3:$T$3,$K$2:$T$2,Y$2,$K4:$T4,"<>N/A"),"")');
     range9.setNumberFormat("0.0%");

   var range10 = sheet.getRange("Z4:Z1000");
  range10.setFormula('=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--($K$2:$T$2<>"")*(LOWER($K4:$T4)<>"n/a"),$K$3:$T$3,$K4:$T4)/SUMIF($K4:$T4,"<>N/A",$K$3:$T$3),"")');
     range10.setNumberFormat("0.0%");  

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Any function that operates on actual spreadsheet cells, are bound to be slow. So use them as little as possible. In your script, you have 19 such calls: `getRange`,  `setNumberFormats` and `setFormula`.

Instead of getting 10 different ranges, and calling `setFormula` and `setNumberFormat` on each of them, get a single range, alter it, and write it back, using `setNumberFormats` and `setFormulas` (note the plural form).

There are API functions for getting arrays of existing formulas and number formats. This could serve as an example:

```
var range = sheet.getDataRange(); // Get a single, large range of all the cells in the sheet
var formulas = range.getFormulas();
var numberFormats = range.getNumberFormats();

// This script operates on two different 'ranges', as an example. Write similar FOR blocks for operations you need to perform.

// Example: Applying formatting and a formula to G4:G1000. 
for (var row = 3; row < 1000; row++) { // the array is 0-based, so 3 refers to row 4
   var column = 6; // refers to column G 
   formulas[row][column] = '=IF(G4="","",WEEKNUM(G4)&"/"&YEAR(G4))';
   numberFormats[row][column] = 'yyyy-mm-dd';
}

// Example: Applying formatting and formula to V4:V1000
for (var row = 3; row < 1000; row++) { // the array is 0-based, so 3 refers to row 4
   var column = 21; // refers to column V
   formulas[row][column] = '=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(--($K$2:$T$2=V$2)*($K4:$T4<>"N/A"),$K$3:$T$3,$K4:$T4)/SUMIFS($K$3:$T$3,$K$2:$T$2,V$2,$K4:$T4,"<>N/A"),"")'
   numberFormats[row][column] = "0.0%";
}

range.setFormulas(formulas); // Write the formulas to the actual cells
range.setNumberFormats(numberFormats); // Apply number formats to the actual cells
```

So here we have limited the number of API calls to 4:

- Get an array of existing formulas
- Get an array of existing number formats
- Write back an array of formulas
- Write back an array of number formats

... which should improve speed significantly.

See the documentation for [`setFormulas`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas) and [`setNumberFormats`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatsnumberformats)