# How do I make this Google Sheets Script faster

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

```
function getCellValue(){
var x=2;
var y=2;
var targetSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var targetSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
var tempNumber = targetSheet1.getRange(y,4).getValue();
var compareNumber = targetSheet2.getRange(x,1).getValue();

 for (j = 0; j<49; j++)
 {
  x=2;
  var i= 0;
  for (i; i<234; i++)
  {
    if (tempNumber == compareNumber)
    {
      targetSheet2.getRange(x,58).setValue(.5);
      x=x+1;
      compareNumber = targetSheet2.getRange(x,1).getValue();
    }
    else
    {
      x=x+1;
      compareNumber = targetSheet2.getRange(x,1).getValue();
    }
  }
   y=y+1;
   tempNumber = targetSheet1.getRange(y,4).getValue();
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Your innermost code runs [49×234=] 11,466 times. I hope obvious, the answer is likely going to involve minimizing what's in those nested loops. No example code, but consider getValue**s** and operating on that array rather than constantly one-off polling and setting cells.

Comment: Hi! If it's possible for you to share a spreadsheet demonstrating your problem, it would be a bit easier to write a fully correct answer.

Comment: This question is related: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/99307/21583

Comment: Please add context and don't just dump code. What are you doing here?

Answer (score 1):

API calls, such as `getRange` and `getValue` are expensive, so you should minimize the *number of times* you get data from your sheet. But there's no apparent cost of getting *a lot* of data in *one* call. You could extract all the values from your sheet, store it in a JavaScript array, and operate on that.

So instead of calling `getRange` etc from within a `for` loop, rewrite so that you get all the data you need beforehand:

```
var SHEET_1_STUDENT_ID_COL_IDX = 3;
var SHEET_2_STUDENT_ID_COL_IDX = 0;

var SHEET_2_UPDATE_COL_IDX = 5;

function faster_getCellValue() {
  var x=2;
  var y=1;

  var targetSheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var targetSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');


  function findSheet2RowByStudentId(studentId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sheet2Values.length; i++) {
      var row = sheet2Values[i];
      if (row[SHEET_2_STUDENT_ID_COL_IDX] === studentId) {
        return i;
      }
    }
  }

  function updateSheet2RowWithValue(rowIdx, colIdx, value) {
    targetSheet2.getRange(rowIdx + 1, colIdx + 1).setValue(value);
  }

  var sheet1Values = targetSheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var sheet2Values = targetSheet2.getDataRange().getValues();

  var studentId = sheet1Values[y - 1][SHEET_1_STUDENT_ID_COL_IDX];

  var sheet2RowIdx = findSheet2RowByStudentId(studentId);

  if (sheet2RowIdx === undefined) {
    return; // Student ID not found in Sheet 2
  }

  updateSheet2RowWithValue(sheet2RowIdx, SHEET_2_UPDATE_COL_IDX, .5);

}
```

Note that I have not tested the above script, but hopefully you will get the general idea so that you're able to implement it on your own:

1. First, copy the sheet's values to a JavaScript array by using `var yourValues = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()`
2. Update the JavaScript array with new values
3. Write the values back to the sheet by using `sheet.getDataRange().setValues(yourValues);`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response. I’m relatively new to both JS and arrays. When running the program it says “TypeError: Cannot Read Property “3” from undefined” referencing line 34 “tempNumber= sheet1Values[y-1][3]”. Would you know how to fix this error?

Comment: So if you're only updating _one_ row, we can simplify a bit. See updated answer.